# Github Actions - Export JSON object from CURL response to ENV variable

Tags: bash, github-actions

Trying to save API responses in their original JSON format as env variables. Getting formatting errors.

```
 echo "GIT_PR_OBJECT=$(curl -u USER:TOKEN https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls/${{ github.event.number }})" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Error from Github:

> Error: Unable to process file command 'env' successfully.

> Error: Invalid environment variable format '  "sha": "123456789",'

My plan is to access this object multiple times throughout the workflow, that way I only  need to make one call to Github API rather than few. Here is how I access the data object saved in the env var.

```
 echo "GIT_EMAIL=$(${{ env.GIT_COMMIT_OBJECT }} | jq -r '.commit.author.email')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

**How can I save my curl response as an env variable in it's JSON format?**

Answer (score 4):

Why not save json content to file instead? Saving to environment variable, while sounds fancy, also smells like a can of worms you don't have to deal with in a first place.

Taking your example:

```yaml
- run:   |
         curl -u USER:TOKEN https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls/${{ github.event.number }} > $HOME/pr.json
         echo "GIT_EMAIL=$(jq -r '.commit.author.email' $HOME/pr.json)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  shell: bash
```

While it is a working solution in my eyes, i fail to understand why it has to be environment variable, which is your main question here.

Comment: I did end up using this method, thank you!